# Use capacitor/geolocation or capacitor-community/background-location?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, geolocation, gps, capacitor

I'm writing an Ionic/Vue 6 mobile app that tracks the route a hiker takes. Now I've got to the part where I need GPS information. The GPS plugin needs to continue to work when the user puts their phone in their pocket for maybe hours at a time. The two plugins I'm looking at are: **capacitor/geolocation** and **capacitor-community/background-location**, so which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have to choose **capacitor-community/background-location** because it can track the position in the background which is not possible with **capacitor/geolocation**.